# how to remove all <div> elements inside a parent <div> in Shiny

Tags: css, r, shiny

I'm hoping I don't need to provide a repro demo here if this question can be answered right away. I'd like to remove all `div` elements under the parent `div with id="daterangescontrol"` everytime I upload a file to my Shiny app. So my code is like this:

```
removeUI(selector = "div#daterangescontrol div")
```

FYI under `div#daterangescontrol`, there are `div#daterange1`, `div#daterange2`...`div#daterange(n)` generated dynamically depending on the number of columns in the dataset, which can be converted to Date. My objective is to remove all these div children when a new file is uploaded (new dataset). However. the above line of code can only remove the first child, e.g. `div#daterange1`. I wonder whether it's because I didn't use the right syntax for the selector. I'm not quite familiar with css. Would anyone please help? Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
The demo code is provided in my other question post: 
[How to validate date range input in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600848/how-to-validate-date-range-input-in-shiny)
please check `removeUI` in `observeEvent(input$file)`.

Comment: rough guess: Did you try: `removeUI(selector = "div#daterangescontrol *")`? Example would be appreciated anyway as potential answers are not only for the OP, but for everyone interested in that question,...

Comment: @BigDataScientist I tried it, it didn't work either. I've provided the demo in my other question post. Check it if you'd like. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
removeUI("#daterangescontrol > div", multiple = T)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.