# How to validate date range input in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

**For testing, please upload a csv file with 1+ column that can be converted to Date in the app.**

My app generates date range inputs (`input$daterange`) dynamically depending on the date columns selected. I'd like to validate each `input$daterange` from 1 to n (the length of `dt$datecols`) to make sure the user won't select `start` date earlier than the oldest date, and `end` date later  than the latest date in the corresponding column. I use `lapply` on `observeEvent` to do that.

For ease of debugging, I pass the value of `input$daterange(i)` to reactive values `dt$daterange(i)` and print `dt$daterange1` (the first date range's value) to the console rendered to check whether the it is smaller or bigger than the `min` and `max` of the corresponding date column, as I did in the `lapply` function. Supposedly, when the check result is `FALSE`, `lappy` function shall display an error message warning the user the `start` or `end` date is not valid, which, however doesn't work. Please find my code below, please check the comments for explanation of problem.

```
library("shiny")
library("DT") # Datatable 
library("rsconnect") # deploy to shinyapps.io
library("shinyjs") # use toggle button from shinyJS pacakage
library("stats")
library("zoo") # to use as.Date() on numeric value

ui <- fluidPage(

      fluidRow(

            column(4,
                  # file upload div
                  fileInput("file", "Choose a file",

                  accept=c(
                  "text/csv", 
                  "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain", 
                  ".csv"
                  )),

                  # show ui for upload file control
                  uiOutput("ui")
            ),


            column(4,
                  # no choices before a file uploaded
                  uiOutput("columnscontrol")
            )

        ),

        hr(),

        fluidRow(
                  column(4,
                         uiOutput("datecolscontrol")),

                  column(6,
                         uiOutput("daterangescontrol"))
        ),

        hr(),

        dataTableOutput("datatbl"),

        # print console for debugging (delete after completion)
        verbatimTextOutput("print_con")

) #end of fluidPage (ui)



# server
server <- function(input, output, session) {


    #########################################################
    #  upload & datatable output
    #########################################################

    # create dataset reactive objects
    dt <- reactiveValues()

    # reset all uis upon new file upload
    observeEvent(input$file, {

        # reset reactive values
        dt$data = NULL
        dt$df = NULL
        dt$cols = NULL
        dt$rows = NULL
        dt$summary = NULL
        dt$colchoices = NULL
        dt$datecols = NULL

        # remove columns div and datecols div when a new file uploaded
        removeUI(selector = "div#columns_div")
        removeUI(selector = "div#datecols_div")

        # remove all <div> elements indside <div>#daterangescontrol:
        removeUI(selector = "div#daterangescontrol div")

        # generate upload file control ui once file uploaded
        output$ui <- renderUI({
          actionButton("readF", "Update")
        })

    })


    # when read file button pressed:
    observeEvent (input$readF, {

        # store data to dt$data
        file <- input$file
        dt$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = TRUE)


        # render columnscontrol
        output$columnscontrol <-  renderUI({

            # get the col names of the dataset and assign them to a list
            dt$colchoices <- mapply(list, names(dt$data))

            # render column group checkbox ui after loading the data
            # tags#div has the advantage that you can give it an id to make it easier to reference or remove it later on
            tags$div(id = "columns_div", 
                     checkboxGroupInput("columns", "", choices = NULL, selected = NULL))
        })

        # render div containing #datecols under datecolscontrol 
        output$datecolscontrol <- renderUI({
            tags$div(id = "datecols_div",
            selectInput("datecols", "Filter data by dates):", choices = NULL, multiple = TRUE, selected = NULL))
        })

    }) 


    # update columns choices when dt$choices is ready
    observeEvent(dt$colchoices, {
        updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "columns", "Select Columns:", choices = dt$colchoices, selected = dt$colchoices)
    })


    # the other reactivity on dt$cols is input$file (when new file uploaded, dt$data and dt$cols set to NULL)
    # so that the following line set apart the reactivity of input$columns on dt$cols
    observeEvent(input$columns, { 
        dt$cols <- input$columns
        dt$df <- dt$data[dt$cols]
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


    # upon any change of dt$df 
    observeEvent(dt$df, {

          f <- dt$df

          # render output$datatbl 
          output$datatbl <- DT::renderDataTable( 
          f, rownames = FALSE,
          filter = 'top',
          options = list(autoWidth = TRUE)
          )

          # update datecols choices with those columns can be converted to Date only:
          dt$date_ok = sapply(f, function(x) !all(is.na(as.Date(as.character(x), format = "%Y-%m-%d"))))
          dt$datecolchoices = colnames(f[dt$date_ok])
          updateSelectInput(session, "datecols", "Filter data by dates:", choices = dt$datecolchoices, selected = NULL)

    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)


    # whenver columns convertable to date updated to choices of input$datecols, convert the columns to Date in the dataset
    observeEvent(dt$datecolchoices, {
        dt$df[dt$date_ok] = lapply(dt$df[dt$date_ok], function(x) as.Date(as.character(x)))
    })


    # generate daterange uis per selected input$datecols
    observeEvent(input$datecols, {

        dt$datecols = input$datecols
        dt$datecols_len = length(dt$datecols)

        # render daterange ui(s) per selected datecols
        output$daterangescontrol <- renderUI({

            # when input$datecols is NULL, no daterange ui
            if ( is.null(input$datecols) ) { return(NULL) }

            # otherwise
            else {

                D = dt$df[dt$rows, dt$cols]

                output = tagList()

                for (i in 1:dt$datecols_len) {
                    output[[i]]= tagList()
                    output[[i]][[1]] = tags$div(id = paste("dateranges_div", i, sep = "_"), 
                                                dateRangeInput(paste0("daterange", i),
                                                paste("Date range of", dt$datecols[[i]]),
                                                start = min(D[[dt$datecols[[i]]]]),
                                                end = max(D[[dt$datecols[[i]]]])))
                }

                # return output tagList() with ui elements
                output
            } 
        }) # end of renderUI
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)

    # loop observeEvent to check whether each input$daterange is valid:
    #### why I can't just call lapply() without observe() as suggested in this post:
    #### https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40038749/r-shiny-how-to-write-loop-for-observeevent
    observe({
      lapply( X = 1:dt$datecols_len, 

              FUN = function(i) { 

                observeEvent(input[[paste0("daterange", i)]], {

                  # update reactive values to test whether this loop is working
                  dt[[paste0("range",i)]] = input[[paste0("daterange", i)]]

                  range = dt[[paste0("range",i)]] 
                  req(range)
                  #########################################
                  ##     CODE BLOCK WITH PROBLEM!!!
                  #########################################
                  # Why the following doesn't work, when I pick a date earlier than the oldest date
                  # no error message shows!
                  shiny::validate(
                    need( range[[1]] >= min(dt$df[[dt$datecols[[i]]]]), "The start date cannot be earlier than the oldest date!"),
                    need( range[[2]] <= max(dt$df[[dt$datecols[[i]]]]), "The end date cannot be later than the latest date!")
                  )
                }) 
              }
        ) # end of lapply
      })

    # rows displayed in input$datatbl (the rendered data table)
    observeEvent( input$datatbl_rows_all, { 
      dt$rows <- input$datatbl_rows_all
    })



    #########################################################
    # print console
    #########################################################
    output$print_con <- renderPrint({

      req(input$daterange1)
      list(
        # to verify whether the observeEvent loop is working for input validation
        # I used dt$range1 to check the first (input$daterange1) against the date range of the corresponding column of the dataset. 
        # It's supposed that when the check result is FALSE (either by selecting a start date earlier than the oldest date or selecting an end date later than the latest date), 
        # the code block with problem shall prompt an error message to warn the user
        min(dt$range1) >= min(dt$df[[dt$datecols[[1]]]]),
        max(dt$range1) <= max(dt$df[[dt$datecols[[1]]]])
      )

    })

} # end of shiny server function

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Please reduce your example to the essential parts which illustrate the problem by following the hints about creating a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Why not sort your list of dates? You only need to compare to `[1]`st and `[n]`th element, and not `[i]` elements.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the exact answer you are looking for but I think it may simplify things. I would simply order your date column which would allow you to select the oldest and newest date. Then set your start and end dates to those two values (see ?dateRangeInput). Lubridate is also a great package for working with dates

Comment: I did set the start and end date for `dateRangeInput`, however, shiny still let user select the date earlier than the start and later than the end.

Comment: Then you need to set the min and max. Those limit the select-able range. Again, see ?dateRangeInput

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem maybe related to the format of your dates.

please look at this post: 
[R: Shiny dateRangeInput format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834778/r-shiny-daterangeinput-format)

you may need to use

```
format(range[[1]])
```